# Save twitch clip from Firefox cache to disk

Tags: firefox, video, cache

I have opened a clip of a twitch broadcast using firefox. I thought about saving the video but when I proceeded to do so, I discovered that the clip has since been removed and all I get is an "access denied". I still have the original tab open and the video plays fine (in the tab).

What I want to do is save the clip on my disk. I tried looking at other questions about how to save cached videos but there doesn't seem to be a file in any cache folders mentioned in those questions. The only thing I can see in `about:cache` is this entry, which presumably is the cache entry for the video:

> predictor-origin:https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/ | 0 bytes | 44 |   2017-01-24 04:50:33 | No expiration time

Previewing the video via View Page Info > Media and playing the Media Preview works fine.

Is there any way that I can save this video?